# 100% height div not getting border outside view area

Tags: css, browser, scroll, height, border

So I made a site where I have a wrapper div. The content is then centered and getting height 100% to make sure is filling the browsers view area. The strange thing is that the main div have a border. If I make my browser small and use the scroll-er to get down on the page. The border is then only showing on the part of the div that was in the view area. When I scroll down the border is not set on the rest of the div. Any one else had this issue? I cant seem to find anything about this particular issue in google.

This is my basic layout

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
html, body {
 background: url('../img/subtle-circles-pattern-2268.png') left top repeat;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
}

#wrapper {
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>  
</head>
    <body>
         <div id="wrapper">
              <div id="content">
                   alot of content<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
              </din>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the Height property from the content ID , The height of the ID will be calculated according to the amount of the content you have on your page so your css should be like

```
#content {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border-left: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
            border-right: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: left;
            width: 940px;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Zan that was the issue

Comment: Hmm maybe I was to fast... removing height from the content ID removes the effect that even though I dont have content enough the div is height 100% of the browser.